# phpexcel -How to change data type for whole column of an excel

Tags: php, excel

I'm trying to change the datatype for a whole column (for eg: i need to change for "M" Column to general format). Its displaying as `2.00` in quantity field,I need to change this whole column to general format ie. display as `"2"`. But its not changing the datatype.

Here is the code:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue(
        $aCells[$eExcelColumn] . $eExcelRow, 
        $sCellData , 
        PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC
    );

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M1:M97')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('0');
```

How to do for the whole column "M" as general format

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PHPExcel doesn't support column or row styling: you need to set the style for a `range` of cells, exactly as you are doing with

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M1:M97')
->getNumberFormat()
->setFormatCode('0');
```

if you want `General` format rather than `'0'`, then set it to `General` Instead:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M1:M97')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('General');
```

or

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M1:M97')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_GENERAL);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried the above but it is not changing the format.

Comment: It should be setting the format to the masking that you specify, whether `General` or `0`.... what version of PHPExcel are you using? What Writer are you using to save your file?

Comment: Hi, Im using Version 14.0

Comment: There isn't a version 14.0 of PHPExcel, the current production release is 1.7.9

Comment: Sorry I thought the version of Excel. The PHPExcel version i use is 1.7.2

Comment: And which Writer? PHPExcel has supported format masking since the very early releases, and certainly should have no problems with setting number format masks even in as old a version as 1.7.2

Comment: Hi, PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_GENERAL worked now thank you

Comment: Okay, but how about many rows down? I used this with 'M1:M2000' and it causes a big performance hit. Maybe it's better to be used just like this: M:M?

Comment: I tried this but it is giving random value ie. I am getting the result as 70709707070709702656
when I am trying to convert 7.07097E+19 
The actual value that I can see in excel formula bar is 70709707070709700000
how to correct it

Comment: @VijayanandPremnath I have the same issue. I am trying FORMAT_TEXT / @ but it display scientific notation of the number.

Answer (score 10):

You can do a column like this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M:M')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_GENERAL);
```

A complete working example. The result in column A has two 2, column B two 2.00

```
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$sheet->getStyle('A:A')
        ->getNumberFormat()
        ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_GENERAL);

$sheet->getStyle('B:B')
        ->getNumberFormat()
        ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_00);

$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 2);
$sheet->setCellValue('A2', 2.0);
$sheet->setCellValue('B1', 2);
$sheet->setCellValue('B2', 2.0);
```

A few more examples for column and row selections that I pulled from my actual base:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('1:1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A:A')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('yyyy/mm');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D:D')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E:E')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('$#,###');
```

Comment: In 2014 when Mark replied he was of course correct, and I am sure back then PHPExcel did not support row or column styling. But I checked active code and use it all the time now.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Interesting... I just tried this again, and it doesn't work for me. I don't know what version of `PHPExcel` I have however as I get `"PHPExcel ##VERSION##, ##DATE##"` when I run `"echo PHPExcel_Calculation_Functions::VERSION();"` I'll believe you that it works.

Comment: Per the changelog.txt file in the root I am using version 1.8.1
Another note; in Excel the desktop app, the order of entering data and setting the style doesn't matter.  But with PHPExcel you have to set the style first, then add text; it won't work the other way around for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mfisinArr = $this->isObject->getAllDataMfisinQuery();
if(isset($mfisinArr) && !empty($mfisinArr))
{
    $excel_row = 2;
    foreach ($mfisinArr as $key => $value) 
    {
        // PHPExcel Style getting default number format
        $object->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$excel_row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0');
        $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $excel_row, sprintf('%09d',$value['security']));
        $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $excel_row, $value['name']);
        $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $excel_row, $value['mf_isin']);
        $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3, $excel_row, empty($value['mat_dt'])?'':date('d-m-Y',strtotime($value['mat_dt'])));
        $excel_row++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For PHPSpreadsheet the solution is

```
$sheet->getStyle('B:B')
     ->getNumberFormat()
     ->setFormatCode(NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_COMMA_SEPARATED1);
```