# How can I convert the value that more than 999 number in PHP Excel as number

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm stuck with this for a few days about PHPExcel.

Why when it comes to 1000 the value convert to text automatically?

But It's normal if in the cell containing the number 0-999.

I have my code and the result below.

Thanks in advance.

[image: image1]
 [image]

Comment: the numbers you highlighted seem ok, what is your problem?

Comment: try to use (int)$row->.. it should work

Comment: Please copy paste your code instead of screenshots

Comment: @madalinivascu when it's more than 1000 it became text so i cannot use that value to calculate further.

Comment: @HamzaNig Thanks a lot I'll try.

Comment: @CharybdeBE lol I'm afraid that all of you don't understand.

Comment: @Nicky its not text, excel is formating the number based on your machine settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H'.$row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want General format rather than 'number', then set it to General Instead:

[phpexcel -How to change data type for whole column of an excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090978/phpexcel-how-to-change-data-type-for-whole-column-of-an-excel)

Comment: I'll try. Thanks a lot